# Can Assign URL address in Variable and use in HTML. using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I Assign URL address in Variable and use in HTML. using JavaScript?

**Example:**

```js
<script>
   var var_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
</script>
```

```html
<a href="var_url"> Click on this link to open www.stackoverflow.com </a>
```

Above is an example to understand my question, I want to use the same URL address many times on HTML page.

Comment: Hi, you should always put some effort into writing a good question for better understanding :) read more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OdjZEY

```
<script>
var var_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
</script>

<p>Open in a new window</p>
<a href="javascript:window.open(var_url);">Click on this link to open www.stackoverflow.com</a>

<p>Open in the same window</p>
<a href="javascript:window.location.href
=var_url;">Click on this link to open www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this is working good as I want.
Sir, when I click on link this is open in another new tab, can this open in same browser tab when click? I tried but can’t work (target="_self").

Answer (score 1):

You could select all anchor tags with the `href` of `var_url` using:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('[href=var_url')]
```

And then change each `href` in this array to be the one stored in `var_url`.

```js
var var_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
[...document.querySelectorAll('[href=var_url]')].forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.href = var_url;
});
```

```html
<a href="var_url">Click on this link to open www.stackoverflow.com</a>
<br />
<a href="var_url">You can also click here to open stackoverflow</a>
```

Alternatively, I think it would be better to use a class on your anchor tags, and set your URLs using:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('var_url')]
```

```js
var var_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
[...document.getElementsByClassName('var_url')].forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.href = var_url;
});
```

```html
<a class="var_url" href="#">Click on this link to open www.stackoverflow.com</a>
<br />
<a class="var_url" href="#">You can also click here to open stackoverflow</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to inject URL in the anchor tag.

```
<a id='anchor_1' href=''>Click on this link to open www.stackoverflow.com</a>

<script>
var var_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
document.getElementById('anchor_1').setAttribute ('href', var_url);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML put id for access that like,

```
<a id="demoLink" href=""> Click on this link to open www.stackoverflow.com </a>
```

you can do this with JavaScript like

```
<script>
   var var_url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

    //change the attribute for anchor tag link
    document.getElementById("demoLink").setAttribute("href", var_url);
</script>
```